# Writing a bomberman AI with Lua / C++

Tags: c++, lua, artificial-intelligence

First, english is not my native langage, but I'll do my best!

I'm actually developing a Bomberman in C++ for a school project and I would like to learn Lua and use it to develop different AIs on it. Unfortunately no one seems to know Lua programming in my school so I'm using the internet!

I've already seen what Lua looks like, and I linked it to some C++ code to see the different behaviours while passing parameters etc...

I've seen different opinions about "why it is cool to use Lua in AI development".

I've seen a lot of explanation about how to use it with C++ but I still don't get it.

For instance, admitting I have an object Map containing the bomberman's map, and an object Monster who will destroy some walls on this map.
Am I suppose to pass the Map to the Lua code, allowing it to change it's contents? Or is the Lua file not supposed to change anything in the C++ objetcs?

I've read about Luabind wich allows to pass some objects from C++ to Lua, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

To have some more general questions about Lua and C++ :

How is the Lua suppose to be aware of some changements in C++ values and stuff (if some others threads are working on it for instance)?

It seems like when you pass an argument to Lua from C++, it is duplicated, is there a way to pass pointers to Lua, so it could always have a look on the changing variables?

I thought it would be able to, at the beginning of the game, launch the AI script and let it do everything, without handling it with C++ afterward, is that really possible?

Answer (score 0):

*1. How Lua is aware of some changes in C++ values?*

This is achieved through so called bindings. You register your classes with Lua along with methods that can be invoked from Lua.

For instance, you have a Monster class in C++ and want Lua to handle its behaviour. You could register a globan function in Lua, which would be called `getMonsterIDsOnTheMap`. That function would return a Lua table with IDs of monsters spawned in the map.

Next, you would register a function called `getMonster`, which would return an instance of a specific monster to Lua. This is where you do bindings that would allow you to manipulate the monster from Lua. Say, your Monster class has functions `move`, `destroyWall`, `getTilePosition` and so on. To give Lua access to this instance of `Monster`, you need a `userdata` object.

From C++, you create a userdata, store in the userdata pointer to your `Monster` instance, assign the userdata `Monster` metatable. In this metatable you register functions `move`, `destroyWall`, etc. You make those functions operate on the instance of your `Monster` through pointer stored in the userdata. After assigning the metatable, you simply return your userdata to Lua, where you can manipulate your monster.

This is actually also an answer to your second question:

*2. It seems like when you pass an argument to Lua from C++, it is duplicated, is there a way to pass pointers to Lua, so it could always have a look on the changing variables?*

*3. I thought it would be able to, at the beginning of the game, launch the AI script and let it do everything, without handling it with C++ afterward, is that really possible?*

Yes, it is possible. You can code core functionality in C++ (sound, graphics, etc), and have Lua handle everything through your bound functions. Of course this might not be trivial to do, but it is possible.

Your question is very broad, so I could not be any more specific. Ask away if you have doubts.